# How to extract a part of data from an excel file

Tags: r

I want to extract the data for India and along the years from this world bank data on co2 emissions. How can I do that using R code for reproducible research?

https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT?downloadformat=excel

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This should most likely do what you want...

```
df = rio::import("API_EN.ATM.CO2E.KT_DS2_en_excel_v2_3469351.xls", which = 1)
df = df[5:270,] # hard code the length
df = df %>% filter(`Data Source` == "India")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{readxl}` package and specify the sheet and range to read:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# Read in the data:
world_bank_data <- readxl::read_xls(
  path = "world-bank-data.xls", 
  sheet = 1, 
  range = "A4:BK270"
)

# Filter rows where country name is India:
india <- world_bank_data |> 
  filter(`Country Name` == "India")
```